# Given a string s, find the longest palindromic substring. Can't understand why code doesn't return proper answer

Tags: python

```
class Solution(object):
    def longestPalindrome(self, s):
        current = ""
        ans = ""

        for n in range(len(s)):
            for index in range(n,len(s)):
                current += s[index]
                print(current)
                if self.ispalindrome(current):
                    print(len(ans),len(current))
                    ans = max(ans,current)
            current = ""
        return ans

    def ispalindrome(self, s):
        return s == s[::-1]
```

I can't understand why the max function ends up choosing the smaller of the two strings on the last iteration. Problem from LeetCode: https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-palindromic-substring/

Comment: `max(ans, current)` returns the latest string lexicographically, not the longest.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`max(ans, current)` returns the latest string lexicographically, not the longest.

You could use `max(ans, current, key=len)` instead. That is, the maximum of the two positional arguments, based on the given function, `len`.